# How to get this PowerShell command output into an iterable collection or array

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, .net-framework-version

[This answer](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Detect-NET-Framework-120ec923) shows how to output a list of computer-names on the domain:

```
   (([adsi]"WinNT://$((Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain)").Children).Where({$_.schemaclassname -eq 'computer'})
```

If the `Path`property is appended

```
 ...  .Where({$_.schemaclassname -eq 'computer'}).Path
```

it outputs a list in this format:

```
      WinNT://{domainname}.net/{machine-name}
```

How would that succession of fully qualified machine names be made into an array or a collection that could be iterated by the script found [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Detect-NET-Framework-120ec923)?

Can that command (i.e. its output) simply be assigned to an array variable?

```
   [array]$ComputerNames = ... (([adsi]"WinNT://$((Get-WMIObject <snip>  ).Path
```

I suspect not, since when I try that

```
$ComputerNames = ... (([adsi]"WinNT://$((Get-WMIObject  <snip>  ).Path
foreach($computer in $ComputerNames) {
    if($regKey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $computer)) {
```

I get an error:

```
Exception calling "OpenRemoteBaseKey" with "2" argument(s): "The network path was not found."
At C:\Users\{myusername}\Get-NetFrameworkVersion.ps1:40 char:8
+     if($regKey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('Lo ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IOException
```

My ultimate goal is to obtain the .NET versions installed on all PCs on the domain.

Comment: The problem is not with assignment to `$ComputerNames`, the problem is the format of the string - try `foreach($Computer in $ComputerNames -replace '^.*?(?=[^/]+$)'){...}` - the `-replace` operation will remove everything up to and including the `/` before the machine name from all the strings, at which point they can be used

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Thanks for the help!